# startService() with Permissions

Tags: android, security, service

So I noticed there is no variant of startService() that accepts a permission.
Isn't this rather dangerous?

I imagined the following simple scenario of an attack:

1. **AppA** calls startService using an explicit intent on "myApp.serviceClass". This service class is to be exported in **AppB**, which has to be installed separately.
2. An attacker could create a malicious version of **AppB**. The latter would export "myApp.serviceClass" as a service and then hijack the data that's included in the intent when **AppA** calls startService().

Am I missing something? I was expecting some variant of startService() that requires the targeted app to possess a specific permission, just as sendBroadcast(intent, permission) does.
How would you prevent such an interference?

Thank you!

Comment: if appa and appb are from the same publisher, a shared user id would solve this.

Comment: @njzk2: First, I fail to see how it would solve this. Second, `sharedUserId` is seriously risky for ordinary SDK developers, as once set, you can never change it.

Comment: @njzk2: Interesting, could you explain this further, please?

Comment: @CommonsWare you could verify that the calling application has the same shareduserid as you do. Except apparently I though you'd have information regarding the calling app in the service call, but it seems you haven't. Damn.

Comment: @njzk2: The OP is interested in the reverse direction anyway, where the client wants to validate the service. You should be able to get user ID info from `PackageManager` somewhere, and so it could be used in that role. However, using `sharedUserId` to validate another app's identity is overkill IMHO. If you happen to be using `sharedUserId` for other reasons, and you wanted to confirm another app is your peer, that's cool, but I wouldn't use `sharedUserId` solely for that job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes. A permission doesn't solve the problem, as the attacker would simply declare that they hold the permission in question. On Android 4.4 and below, [if the attacker is installed first, the user might not even know about this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md). Or, the user could blindly agree to the permission.

> How would you prevent such an interference?

It is incumbent on the client to validate that the service is the proper implementation. One solution is to validate the signing key used to sign the service's APK file, comparing it to a known value. My [CWAC-Security](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/) library has [a `SignatureUtils` class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/#usage-signatureutils) for this purpose. This [pair of sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/SigCheck) illustrates the approach.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. But still, if you set the protection level to signature, the attacking app would at least have to be signed with the same certificate; assuming the correct app is installed first.

Comment: @Knight: Correct. But the scenario where both apps are from the same developer, and the `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, is a niche at the moment. Note that broadcasts are the only one of the four component IPC models where the requester can use a permission to validate the responder. There is no `startActivity()` that takes a permission, nor is there a mirror set of methods on `ContentResolver` that take a permission for working with a provider. All of those cases require a signature check or similar approaches as well.